# Spring JPA @Table schema, get value from applicaiton.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Is it possible?**

I have tried with the sample code below but not working.

I want to set the value to the schema as a dynamic value gets from application.properties.

Or have any solutions?

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "${test-scname}", name = "XXX")
public class ABCTable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7418875659416987527L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

**In application.properties**

```
test-scname=ABC
```

**JPA LOGS**

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        abctable0.ID as id1_0,
        abctable0.NAME as name2_0
    from
        ${test-scname}.XXX abctable0 
    where
        abctable0.ID=?
```

Comment: Yuo cannot. Values in annotations have to be statics, the support for resolving values is build into the processors for those annotations. As `@Table` is a JPA annotations this will not support translating those to an actual value. You might be able to dynamically set the `default-schema` property for hibernate but this would apply to everything.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you